# how do I link pages on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three resources for my demo_app that I made. I made a home page but I wanted to put links of my home page to link to my three resources. I put out the code

```
<%= link_to 'users', @user %> | 
<%= link_to 'microposts', @micropost %> |
<%= link_to 'task', @task %> |
```

on my home page and the links show up on the page but they don't work

routes.rb file

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
      get "static_pages/home"

      resources :tasks

      resources :microposts

      resources :users

      root :to => 'static_pages#home'
    end
```

what I want to do is link to the index page of each of these like the one here

```
<h1>Listing tasks</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.name %></td>
        <td><%= task.status %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>
```

and also have a link back to the home page. sorry is this a funky question?

Comment: Marshall, it  may be helpful to move your goal to the very first part of the message, your "what I want do..." is buried between code-blocks and easily missed.

Answer (score 4):

Please look into http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html - it is a great reference! Depending on what the link target is supposed to be you are probably looking for:

```
<%= link_to 'User (view)', user_path(@user) %>
<%= link_to 'User (edit)', edit_user_path(@user) %>
<%= link_to 'User (index)', users_path %>
```

Best, 
Ben.

Answer (score 2):

In your view you want to use an appropriate path helper for each. To get the index pages:

```
<%= link_to 'users', users_path %>
<%= link_to 'microposts', microposts_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your tasks controller, in the index method,  set those three variables to the values you want,

e.g. `@user=current_user, @micropost = @user.micropost, etc.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
<%= link_to 'users', :controller =>"user" %>
<%= link_to 'microposts', :controller =>"micropost" %>
<%= link_to 'task', :controller => "task" %>
```

reference by [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)